# sparklyr spark_read_parquet from s3 error

Tags: r, sparklyr

When I read a parquet file on s3 from sparklyr context like this:

```
{spark_read_parquet(sc, name = "parquet_test", path = "s3a://<path-to-file>")}
```

It throws me an error which is:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=s3a: .....

I was able to read the parquet file in a sparkR session by using read.parquet() function. So there must be some differences in terms of spark context configuration between sparkR and sparklyr.

Any suggestions on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `yarn-client` mode, The file schema `s3` that you are using is not correct. You'll need to use the `s3://<path-to-file>`